# Managing configuration of distributed systems with AWS SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I'm wondering if it's possible to use AWS for configuration management of distributed webservices with something like SQS without having to manage an instance of ZooKeeper, etcd or something else.

Webservice A regularly needs to push a configuration change to all instances of Webservice B (and C, and D, etc.) without knowing the details of Webservice B.

I know I can use long polling with SQS (for 20 seconds, which is fine). It's also possible to set the message visibility to 0 seconds making it available to all consumers.

However after a consumer reads the message and then long polls for new messages, is there a way to prevent it from reading messages it has already read and wait for new messages?

Maybe set a message TTL for 10 seconds and delay the next read for 10 seconds, but this feels more like a hack than using it correctly.

Comment: Have you considered CodeDeploy to push these changes?

Comment: I'm not really sure how code deploy would help. Services will be running on Elastic Beanstalk and will be able to pull the configuration when launched, however if a webservice changes a configuration value it needs a way of pushing that change to all instances of a different service that are already running.

Comment: I did not know you were on EB.  CodeDeploy would not work for this.

Comment: SQS is the wrong service for this. Only one server would get the message from the queue. Instead, you could use SNS to broadcast a message to all subscribers. You wouldn't even have to poll, you would just need to expose an endpoint for SNS to hit.

Comment: Not sure SNS would work very easily. The webservice instances are rather fluid and not able to easily subscribe themselves, they don't even know their own location. Also you can have multiple servers can get the same message from the queue by setting visibility to 0 seconds (turning it off) but I need to be able to prevent a service from reading existing messages it has already read.

Comment: Your suggestion of setting visibility to 0 seems like a total hack, and just presents other problems like the fact that you would never know when you can remove the item from the queue, so all your listeners would just sit there reading the same item off the queue over and over again. You are trying to use SQS for something it wasn't designed for, and isn't a good fit for at all. SQS just isn't going to work for this.

Comment: If SNS isn't going to work, then I would look into Redis Pub/Sub and use ElastiCache. If you can live with it being a bit less "realtime" then I would look into updating a database table (RDS or DynamoDB) or an S3 object and have your servers periodically check the "last updated" timestamp on the database table or S3 object.